# "unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" on one computer but not another with PHP 5

Tags: php, php-5.2

My local computer runs PHP 5.3.2, while my server runs 5.2.5. I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

with

```
$productsIterator = $productModule::load(Phlex_Db_Order::Asc('name'));
```

I assume the error happens because PHP 5.2.5 doesn't support $stringClassName::methodName() syntax.

Does anyone know either 1) a workaround or 2) some other reason this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One workaround will be

```
 call_user_func(array($productModule, "load"), Phlex_Db_Order::Asc('name'));
```

or, according to the manual since 5.2.3:

```
 call_user_func($productModule."::load", Phlex_Db_Order::Asc('name'));
```

Only one thing to [note:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

> the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference.

And for completeness' sake, you are right, "dynamic" calling of static methods was added in 5.3.0. From the [PHP 5 change log](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php):

> Added support for dynamic access of static members using `$foo::myFunc()`. (Etienne Kneuss)

Comment: +1, and if you need pass by reference, you can use `call_user_func_array($callback, array(&$param1, &$param2));`...