# Cant get static variable from $class

Tags: php, class, scope

I have a question regarding "dynamic" class initialising, let me explain what I mean:

```
$class = 'User';
$user = new $class();

//...is the same as doing
$user = new User();
```

So... that's not the problem, but I am having some trouble doing the same while calling a static variable from a class, for example:

```
$class = 'User';
print $class::$name;
```

Which gives out the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in

Off course I have tested doing `print User::$name;` and that works. So class works.

Why is this and is there a way around it?

***Follow up question:***
Also is there any valid reasons to not use this "dynamic" way in creating classes?

Comment: you cannot mix dynamic and static calls, that is why it is impossible to call User::$$prop and also your $class::$name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679717/unexpected-t-paamayim-nekudotayim-on-one-computer-but-not-another-with-php-5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access a static variable by $var::$reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675676/access-a-static-variable-by-varreference)

Comment: I don't like this method of doing what you're trying to achieve. How can you guarantee that the class stored in the string `$class` has the static variable `$name` in it? If you can guarantee that then I can see no reason to be storing the class name in a variable.

Comment: @ThomasClayson is my case I use it to load plugin classes which all have identical "metadata" in variables, such as version and name. All plugin classes are extending and implementing to make sure they have correct structure and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have PHP version of 5.3 and above, and you don't want to use reflection (which in my opinion is an overkill - unless you want to access multiple static properties) you can define getter function and call it via call_user_func():

```
class A {
    public static $var = "Hello";
    public static function getVar() {
        return self::$var;
    }
}
$className = "A";
echo call_user_func(array($className, 'getVar'));
```

Comment: Well, that is certainly a work around to the problem... Thanks!

Comment: Even easier workaround seems to be; `$vars = get_class_vars($className);`

Answer (score 2):

This code works good on PHP 5.4.3:

```php
<?php

class A {
    public static $var = "Hello";
}

print(A::$var);

$className = "A";
print($className::$var);

?>
```

Comment: This is the code that the OP has. Presumably (although he hasn't stated) he must be using an earlier version of PHP.

Comment: Well, then I know it is my PHP version that is the problem. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer from the question I linked in the comments:

> You can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.reflection) to do this. Create a [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php#language.oop5.reflection.reflectionclass)
> object given the classname, and then use the getStaticPropertyValue
> method to get the static variable value.
>
> ```
> class Demo
> {
>     public static $foo = 42;
> }
>
> $class = new ReflectionClass('Demo');
> $value=$class->getStaticPropertyValue('foo');
> var_dump($value);
> ```

Comment: using reflection seems to be overkill solution unless you mean to use it on large number of properties of static classes, but yeah, using reflection will get you the needed result

Comment: Also, it sounds by the error message that OP is using a version of php before whichever version (5.3.something) which has proper support for static classes and static class variables and as such this may be the best option.

Comment: What is the real differences here from just creating the "real" class and then getting my variable? Like: `$user = new $class(); print $user->name;`? Is there a performance gain from using Reflection?

Comment: static and instance variables are two different things. I would probably use instance variables and do what you want, reflection is quite a roundabout way to do what you need. For what you need just use instance variables (I assume that you're instantiating the class at some point anyway?)